# Exception of type 'System.PlatformNotSupportedException' was thrown in non-sharepoint website

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I'm running a web app on Win2008 server that used to have Sharepoint installed but now disabled.  My website has nothing to do with Sharepoint, does not use it, does not call any functions, etc.  However, I'm getting this error.  What's going on and how can I fix this?  making Sharepoint not a part of my web app?  My web app is running under .Net 4.0 integrated mode app pool on IIS7.  This error below is from event log. I really want to remove SharePoint completely from this server but ran into multiple other issues as well so I already stopped all services and websites related to SharePoint but still getting this error.

Application information: 
    Trust level: Full

Process information: 
    Process ID: 7720 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

Exception information: 
    Exception type: PlatformNotSupportedException 
    Exception message: Exception of type 'System.PlatformNotSupportedException' was thrown.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.get_Farm()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.FindLocal(SPFarm& farm, Boolean& isJoined)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.get_Local()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.AlternateServerUrlFromHttpRequestUrl(Uri url)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAlternateUrl.get_ContextUri()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPControl.GetContextWebApplication(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.ServerContext.GetContext(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.ServerContext.get_Current()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.SqlSessionStateResolver.System.Web.IPartitionResolver.ResolvePartition(Object key)
   at System.Web.PartitionManager.GetPartition(IPartitionResolver partitionResolver, String id)
   at System.Web.SessionState.SqlSessionStateStore.GetConnection(String id, Boolean& usePooling)
   at System.Web.SessionState.SqlSessionStateStore.DoGet(HttpContext context, String id, Boolean getExclusive, Boolean& locked, TimeSpan& lockAge, Object& lockId, SessionStateActions& actionFlags)
   at System.Web.SessionState.SqlSessionStateStore.GetItemExclusive(HttpContext context, String id, Boolean& locked, TimeSpan& lockAge, Object& lockId, SessionStateActions& actionFlags)
   at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.GetSessionStateItem()
   at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.BeginAcquireState(Object source, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Request information: 
    Is authenticated: True 
    Authentication Type: Forms 
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 5 
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 
    Is impersonating: True 
    Stack trace:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.get_Farm()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.FindLocal(SPFarm& farm, Boolean& isJoined)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.get_Local()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.AlternateServerUrlFromHttpRequestUrl(Uri url)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAlternateUrl.get_ContextUri()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPControl.GetContextWebApplication(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.ServerContext.GetContext(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.ServerContext.get_Current()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.SqlSessionStateResolver.System.Web.IPartitionResolver.ResolvePartition(Object key)
   at System.Web.PartitionManager.GetPartition(IPartitionResolver partitionResolver, String id)
   at System.Web.SessionState.SqlSessionStateStore.GetConnection(String id, Boolean& usePooling)
   at System.Web.SessionState.SqlSessionStateStore.DoGet(HttpContext context, String id, Boolean getExclusive, Boolean& locked, TimeSpan& lockAge, Object& lockId, SessionStateActions& actionFlags)
   at System.Web.SessionState.SqlSessionStateStore.GetItemExclusive(HttpContext context, String id, Boolean& locked, TimeSpan& lockAge, Object& lockId, SessionStateActions& actionFlags)
   at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.GetSessionStateItem()
   at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.BeginAcquireState(Object source, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)